# What does the 1 represent at the end of a nullable type?

Tags: c#

A nullable variable such as:

`int? kitten;`

has a type of `` kitten.Nullable`1 ``

What does the 1 represent?

For context only, the reason for asking this question was my musings over:

If I have this value in a string (no access to the actual object/type/reference), and I want to determine if it is nullable or not, would checking `` .endsWith(".Nullable`1") `` be consistently OK or would the number change depending on some unforseen factor?

Comment: The number won't change because it's the number of generic arguments to the underlying `Nullable<int>` type, and that's always 1. As for your main question...

Comment: Also this question would most probably have been better as 2 questions (as they are are not completely related to each other and could easily / probably better be answreed separately.

Comment: @OP also: From what I read from our question it COULD be that it is similar but sufficiently different form the other question to not really be a duplicate of it (as that one asks for objects nullable but YOU seem to ask if a value in a string is nullable?). maybe if you could elaborate that more then it could be that your question is different enough (at least if the other question didn't already answer you)

Comment: I wasn't asking how to check if a type is nullable, I was just adding some context. Also this was specifically if you have the type as a string, not if you have access to the type object (asp.net mvc model validation will give you the parameter type as a string, not as a type). Thanks for the specific answer Frederic. I have clarified in the question for googlers. This is *not* a duplicate.

Comment: NOW it's a duplicate! Incredibly hard to google/search questions like what does `1 mean :-)